# Error while filtering DataFrame based on boolean expression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter my DataFrame based on the following expression:

`df = df[not(df['var1'] == (1 or 2 or 3) and df['var2'].isnull())]`

Essentially, I would like to keep the dataframe without the rows where var1 has a value of 1, 2 or 3 and there is no input for var2. However, I get the following return:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I don't know which one to use and when I use a couple of them they return an empty DataFrame. How can I solve this?

Comment: Use `&` not `and`, also `1 or 2 or 3` is always True, use `df['var1'].isin([1,2,3])`

Comment: Did not solve the issue unfortunately

Comment: please read the duplicates carefully, and clearly show what you tried. `not` is also invalid for Series, you need to use `~`